# Error while averaging values extracted from finviz

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So while building my dividend investing portfolio spreadsheet, I am extracting the annual Yield% values for respective stocks from the website finviz, and even though the value extraction works perfectly fine, the problem comes when I try to find the average of the cells that contain those values.

For example, in the table below: cell `B2` extracts the `Annual Dividend Yield%` of `VTI` (which is in cell `A2`) by **using the formula**:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),8,2),"","")="-","", 
    SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),8,2),"",""))
```

I get

```
╔═══╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║   ║       A       ║           B            ║
╠═══╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Symbol        ║ Annual Dividend Yield% ║
║ 2 ║ NYSEARCA:VTI  ║ 1.72%                  ║
║ 3 ║ NYSEARCA:SPHD ║ 5.63%                  ║
║ 4 ║               ║ #DIV/0!                ║
╚═══╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

Now when I try to **find the average of the annual dividend yield% in Cell `B4`**, using the formula:

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B3)
```

then I get this error of `#DIV/0!`
I am assuming it is because of me scraping the data from finviz and then trying to average, but not sure!

**Regardless, is there a way to get around this and find the average% ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula results are text including the `*` as well as the `%` symbols.
You need to change your formula so you get a number instead.

```
=IF(REGEXREPLACE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),8,2),"\*|%","")*1="-","", 
    REGEXREPLACE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),8,2),"\*|%","")*1)
```

What we actually do is change the `SUBSTITUTE` function to the `REGEXREPLACE` one and change the result from text to a number by using `*1`

Comment: So i need it to be in the %age form i.e 1.72% instead of just 1.72, so I changed *1 to *0.01 and then used the sheets Percent format for that column! Is that the right way to go?

Comment: Another Problem: If a particular stock or ETF does not have a dividend% then from finviz it extracts - sign and thus I wrote an IF rule such that if it is equal to - sign then make the cell empty but now it gives me the error of "-" is a text and cannot be coerced to a number!

Comment: Most likely you need to use the `IFERROR` function as well. If still in trouble, share the new formula